# Extraction of MS Office properties

Tags: c#, text, ms-office, metadata, text-extraction

I want to extract the contents of a MS Office file using C#. 
For example: i want to open a doc/docx/xls/xlsx/ppt/pptx and be able to extract the text and infos like (number of pages - word, number of sheets - excel, number of slides - ppt, number of graphs - excel, number of images - powerpoint, etc etc etc).
I realized that I can extract the text using Windows iFilter. But this only give me the text. Anyone know a dll or something that can give me this kind of information? If not, is there any site that explains with detail the skeleton of an office xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For docx/xlsx/pptx MS offers a free library called [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) which you can use to achieve what you asked...

For doc/xls/ppt (older/binary) I do not know of a free library - there are some commercial libraries that support this:

- [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (DOC and DOCX)
- [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) (XLS and XLSX)
- [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) (XLS and XLSX)
- [SpreadSheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) (XLS and XLSX)
- [Aspose.Slides](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.slides-for-.net/default.aspx) (PPT and PPTX)
- [Spire.Office](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/spire-office-for-net.html) (DOC and DOCX and XLS and XLSX)

The commercial libraries usually offer a very rich set of features - for example export to PDF...

Comment: this perhaps is a good choice. Probably I could programatically change a doc to a docx and then call the OpenXML SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The Office XML format is explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(v=office.12).aspx

It's worth reading the Wikipedia article to orient yourself before diving in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats